# "Cluster validation error: Validation failed for enable_elastic_disk, the value must be true (is \\"true\\")"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, operators, databricks

I am receiving below error while trying to create cluster in databricks using airflow.

```
"Cluster validation error: Validation failed for enable_elastic_disk, the value must be true (is \\"true\\")"
```

I couldn't resolve this error even after setting the value to true. Can anyone help with this.

below is my code:

```
 new_cluster = {
        "cluster_name": "****",
        'spark_version': '9.1.x-scala2.12',
        'node_type_id': 'c5.xlarge',
        'aws_attributes': {'availability': 'ON_DEMAND'},
        'enable_elastic_disk': True,
        # "autoscale": {
        #     "min_workers": 2,
        #     "max_workers": 8
        # },
        'num_workers': 8,
        'policy_id': '*****'
    }
```

I couldn't resolve this error even after setting the value to true. Can anyone help with this.

Comment: Which SDK function are you passing this `new_cluster` dict to?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in apache airflow databricks provider, and they fixed it in this [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/25394), it's available since the version [3.2.0](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/index.html#id7), so you just need to upgrade to >= 3.2.0 in order to solve the problem

```bash
pip install apache-airflow-providers-databricks>=3.2.0
```